# How to make not generate a number twice?

Tags: java, android

In my program i am using a random generator.

```
Random random = new Random();

//How i use it
int i = random.nextInt(numberNeeded);
```

The problem is, is that i need to find a way that each number only gets generated once. So i guess its not complete random....For example....When number 1 is generated, i dont want it to be called again, but instead call one of the other numbers...Like 2,3, or 4...Then when 4 is call it only can call 2 or 3..

then the next time the numbers get shuffled and then it repeats the process...

The numbers will need to range from 4 to 16

Answer (score 7):

It would probably be much easier to use [Collections.shuffle](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%3C?%3E%29) on a list of the elements you want to select from:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=4; i<=16; i++)
    numbers.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(numbers);
// numbers is now in a random order and contain the numbers 4 through 16
```

Comment: so i how would i generate a random number from this? such as int = random.nextInt()

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 - the first random number would be `numbers.get(0)`, the `second numbers.get(1)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Firsly make sure you do `new Random()` only once, when your application first starts.

Secondly, remember the last value in a variable, and loop forever until it doesn't match.

```
Random random = new Random();

int lastNumber = -1;

while (true)
{
  int i = random.nextInt(numberNeeded);
  if (i == lastNumber) continue;
  lastNumber = i;
  break;
}
```

Comment: it fails on 1st iteration only bcoz if  i=4 for 1st iteration then if(i==lastNumber) returns false as i=4 and lastNumber=-1 so loop breaks

Answer (score 0):

add the numbers 4 through 16 to an ArrayList then shuffle it with Collections.shuffle(...). Then return them in ArrayList order

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collections.shuffle...

```
            //Setup your list as needed...
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {
            1, 2, 3, 4 }));


    // Randomizes the list
    Collections.shuffle(list);

    for (Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
                    //Removes from the list...
        i.remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way, but the most straight forward way would be to use a boolean array.

```
//create an array of boolean values set to TRUE
boolean[] isavailable = new boolean[somesize];
Arrays.fill(isavailable, Boolean.TRUE);

//Get a random number
Random r = new Random();
int myrandomnumber=r.nextInt()%25; //Im just going to use 25 for example

if (isavailable[myrandomnumber])
{
   isavailable[myrandomnumber]=false;
   //do whatever you want with the number here
}
else
{
     //Generate another random number here
}
```

In all honesty, its probably best to put this into a while loop, that way you are covered if you generate more than two unavailable numbers in a row, but this should give you the basic idea.